# Flatten a list of nested maps in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm trying to flatten a list of nested maps, so that the output is list of maps which can then be inserted into a database table. The nested maps could contain a list of maps. In general a minimal example of the nested map would be something like this:

```
  %{
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: [
      %{
        d: "d1",
        e: [%{f: "f1", g: "g1"}],
        h: "h1",
        i: "i1"
      },
      %{
        d: "d2",
        e: [%{f: "f2", g: "g2"}],
        h: "h2",
        i: "i2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The output I'd be looking for is:

```
  [
    %{f: "f1", g: "g1", d: "d1", h: "h1", i: "i1", b: "b", a: "a"},
    %{f: "f2", g: "g2", d: "d2", h: "h2", i: "i2", b: "b", a: "a"}
  ]
```

The length of the list is equal to the number of "terminal" maps (ie. the `f` key in this example). Also you'll note that where the nesting takes place, `c` and `e`, those keys are not necessary and therefore are dropped.

I have tried to recurse over the map keys, but the issue I run into is that the output is always the length of then number of keys in the parent map.

Any help or ideas on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen if the nested map has the same key as the map on the level above? Maps cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: All keys are unique, so I don’t have to account for that.

Comment: `'a'` is a list and value for `c` key is a list; why would you want the latter to expand and the first to not?

Comment: I think I get tripped up with the single quote vs double quote in Elixir. `'a'` is actually a string not a charlist, whereas `c` is a list. And so I'm only expanding the lists. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we need to literally *fork* traversing the level when we meet a list as a value, our best friend would be [`Task.async_stream/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html?#async_stream/3). Once we are to perform it lazily, all the internal operations are also lazy, until we need to terminate the result to return it from `flatten/1` (with `Enum.to_list/1`.)

```rb
defmodule Flat do
  @spec flatten(map()) :: [map()]
  def flatten(input),
    do: input |> do_flatten([%{}]) |> Enum.to_list()

  @doc "here we fork it in parallel and collect results"
  defp do_flatten([%{}|_] = input, acc) do
    input
    |> Task.async_stream(&do_flatten(&1, acc))
    |> Stream.flat_map(&elem(&1, 1))
  end

  @doc """
    add `{key, value}` pairs to each list
    in currently accumulated result
  """
  defp do_flatten(%{} = input, acc) do
    Stream.flat_map(acc, fn list ->
      Enum.reduce(input, [list], &do_flatten(&1, &2))
    end)
  end

  @doc "enumerable as value → go for it"
  defp do_flatten({_k, v}, acc) when is_list(v) or is_map(v),
    do: do_flatten(v, acc)

  @doc "the leaf, add to all lists in the accumulator"
  defp do_flatten({k, v}, acc),
    do: Stream.map(acc, &Map.put(&1, k, v))
end
```

```rb
input = %{
  a: "a", b: "b",
  c: [
    %{d: "d1", e: [%{f: "f1", g: "g1"}], h: "h1", i: "i1"},
    %{d: "d2", e: [%{f: "f2", g: "g2"}], h: "h2", i: "i2"}]
}

Flat.flatten()
#⇒ [
#    %{a: "a", b: "b", d: "d1", f: "f1", g: "g1", h: "h1", i: "i1"},
#    %{a: "a", b: "b", d: "d2", f: "f2", g: "g2", h: "h2", i: "i2"}
#  ]
```

Here is a blog post explaining this technique in details on the example of [“Wolf, Goat, Cabbage” riddle](https://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2020/08/04/wolf-goat-cabbage-and-elixir).

Comment: That was a very timely blog post. Thanks for the solution I’m still working through the details. I always thought lazy loading was a solution to performance and memory. Any advice on how you approach a problem like this and how you end up debugging as you work through the problem.

Comment: Lazy processing is basically about how we deal with enumerables. Greedy operations (from `Enum` module) apply the action to all elements in the enumerable and return the intermediate result. Lazy (`Stream`) pass each element through all the actions in the chain. Here it it preferrable, because the enumerable expands between operations. We start with a list of length 1 and end up with a list of arbitrary length.

Comment: Bits of advice is hard :) I definitely do not start writing code until I realized the path I am to follow. I have attempted this with `Access.all/0`, then realized it won’t suit and switched to lazy tasks. At any step, I do use `IO.inspect/0` (terminating the stream before I wanted to inspect it.)

Comment: I appreciate it. The key insight here, looks to me, that you need a lazy function call, when forking at lists. This way you are passing the same accumulator to each branch at the fork. FYI I ran this code on a list of maps that had ~7000 terminal nodes and it worked, with an arbitrary number of branches. I'm just validating the data now!

Comment:  it does not depend on how deep the nested level is, actually. Once it works for 2 levels, it works for 1M, the only issue might be a performance. BTW, one might fork greedily with `Task.async/1` and [`Task.yield_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html?#yield_many/2-example) as shown in the example under this link, but it might gorge the whole memory when one has 7000 terminal nodes :)